# Registry entry differs in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: .net, windows-7, registry, windows-7-x64

I have installed a software Foxit Reader (PDF reader)

My application checks whether this software has been installed or not by checking the following entry exists or not.

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader**

It seeems to have worked fine in all windows OS except Windows 7 64 bit. On investigating I find that the registry entry for this software is located in a different location. below is the location.

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Foxit Software**

How can I check whether Foxit Reader is installed or not correctly and it should work in all versions of Windows OS.

Thanks. Any help much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

Wow6432Node is where the 32 bit entries live.  64 bit is at HKLM\Software.  In .net 4.0, the ability was added to read tehm easily.

See this for example code:

http://www.rhyous.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa/

Without 4.0, you will have to impport advapi32.dll and use RegOpenKeyEx, RegCloseKey, and RegQueryValueEx.

Comment: Wow6432Node is where the _32-bit_ registry entries live. 64-bit entries are where you expect: `HKLM\Software`. 32-bit programs, like Foxit can be are stored under `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node` unless the program explicitly requests the key without virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably check both locations. You could specifically look in the 32-bit registry location, but then you'd be unable to detect a 64-bit version of Foxit (should it ever be created).